# vba pivot table in new sheet of same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

With the help of below coding, I am able to create Pivot table. I am facing problem when I change the table destination to another sheet.

If I use below coding, it is working fine.

`Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PTCache, Tabledestination:=Range("A1"))`

If I use below coding, it is showing error as invalid procedure.

`Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PTCache, Tabledestination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A1"))`

Complete code.

```
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim PTCache As PivotCache

Worksheets("Sheet3").Select
Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PTCache, Tabledestination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A1"))
Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion)
With PT
.PivotFields("phase").Orientation = xlColumnField
.PivotFields("month").Orientation = xlColumnField
.PivotFields("vertical").Orientation = xlRowField
.PivotFields("pp").Orientation = xlDataField
.DisplayFieldCaptions = False
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Row number and Column number referencing syntax.

This works for me:

```
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim PTCache As PivotCache
Worksheets("Sheet3").Select
Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion)
Set PT = PTCache.CreatePivotTable("Sheet4!R1C1", "PivotPP")
With PT
.PivotFields("phase").Orientation = xlColumnField
.PivotFields("month").Orientation = xlColumnField
.PivotFields("vertical").Orientation = xlRowField
.PivotFields("pp").Orientation = xlDataField
.DisplayFieldCaptions = False
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
Tabledestination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Name & "!R1C1"
```